# Change order of elements found by re.findall

Tags: python, regex

If I have a regex like this for example:

```
>>> text = 'asd321zxcnmzasd5'
>>> re.findall('(asd)(\d*)', text)
[('asd', '321'), ('asd', '5')]
```

How can I make it change the order of the elements in the tuples? Like this for example:

```
[('321', 'asd'), ('5', 'asd')]
```

The tuples might have more than 2 elements, so I don't want to merely reverse the order, or reverse the text before applying the regex and use some lookahead/lookbehind functions. I want to know whether I can somehow set the order in the RegEx the way I would give it a name with `(?P<name>...)`

Comment: Why does the order matter?

Comment: I have multiple regex on similar patterns, but they search differently so the order is not consistent. I'd like all of them to return the elements in the same order

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `finditer` instead of `findall`:

```
>>> for res in re.finditer('(?P<str>asd)(?P<dig>\d*)', text):
...    print (res.group('dig'),res.group('str'))                                                                                                                          
... 
('321', 'asd')
('5', 'asd')

>>> [(res.group('dig'),res.group('str')) for res in re.finditer('(?P<str>asd)(?P<dig>\d*)', text)]                                                                                     
[('321', 'asd'), ('5', 'asd')]
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use a namedtuple. Something like this (untested)

```
from collections import namedtuple

NT = namedtuple('NT', 'first second')

def my_order(m):
    new_order = []
    for item in m:
        new_order.append((item.second, item.first))
    return new_order


m = re.findall(NT('(asd)(\d*)'), text)
my_m = my_order(m)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can reverse the tuples using

```
a=[('asd', '321'), ('asd', '5')]
a= [tuple(reversed(i)) for i in a]
print a
print a[0][0]
[('321', 'asd'), ('5', 'asd')]
```